# Confusion with ARGF#set_encoding

Tags: ruby, encoding, character-encoding

[`ARGF.set_encoding`](http://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/ARGF#set_encoding-instance_method) says:

> If single argument is specified, strings read from ARGF are tagged with the encoding specified.
>
> If two encoding names separated by a colon are given, e.g. "ascii:utf-8", the read string is converted from the first encoding (external encoding) to the second encoding (internal encoding), then tagged with the second encoding.

So I tried the below:

```
p RUBY_VERSION
p ARGF.external_encoding
ARGF.set_encoding('ascii')
p ARGF.readlines($/)
```

*output:*

```
D:\Rubyscript\My ruby learning days>ruby true.rb a.txt
"2.0.0"
#<Encoding:IBM437>
["Hi! How are you?\n", "I am doing good,thanks."]

p RUBY_VERSION
p ARGF.external_encoding
ARGF.set_encoding(ARGF.external_encoding,'ascii')
p ARGF.readlines($/)
```

*output:*

```
D:\Rubyscript\My ruby learning days>ruby true.rb a.txt
"2.0.0"
#<Encoding:IBM437>
["Hi! How are you?\n", "I am doing good,thanks."]
```

No encoding change is found. So please advice me the correct approach.

Comment: Please stop tagging questions with `[ruby-2.0]`. Unless they *are* specific to that version.

Comment: what is the purpose of ``ARGF.set_encoding`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Encoding `IBM437` and `ASCII` (and `UTF-8`) has the same byte sequence for ASCII characters. So you won't see the difference from `String#inspect`. However, you can check the `String#encoding` value for the input strings.

```rb
p RUBY_VERSION
p ARGF.external_encoding
ARGF.set_encoding(ARGF.external_encoding,'ascii')
p ARGF.readlines($/).map{|s| s.encoding}
```

In Ruby (**1.9 and higher version**), String is a byte sequence tagged with some encoding. You can get the encoding from `String#encoding`.

So the Chinese word "中" can be represented different ways:

```
e4 b8 ad          # tagged with encoding UTF-8
d6 d0             # tagged with encoding GBK
2d 4e             # tagged with encoding UTF-16le
```

I will always write my script in UTF-8, that is, the internal encoding for my script is UTF-8. Some times I want to process text file (e.g. named "a.txt" and has content "中") encoded with GBK. Then I can set the external encoding and the internal encoding for the IO object and Ruby will do the conversion for me.

```rb
ARGF.set_encoding('GBK', 'UTF-8')
str = ARGF.readline
puts str.encoding

# run             $ script.rb a.txt
```

Ruby reads `"\xd6\xd0"` from "a.txt" and since I have specified the external encoding as GBK, it tags the data with encoding GBK. And I have specified the internal encoding as UTF-8 so Ruby do a conversion from GBK byte sequence to UTF-8, which results in `"\xe4\xb8\xad"` with tag UTF-8. And this string has the same encoding as other strings in my script, so I can use it with ease.

This is useful because a lot of String methods fail when the two String operands has different, incompatible encoding. For example:

```rb
# encoding: utf-8
a = "中"                  # tagged with UTF-8
b = "中".encode('gbk')    # tagged with GBK
puts a + b
#=> Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and GBK
```

Comment: Yes! it does work now. But why `.map{|s| s.encoding}` needed?

Comment: @iAmRubuuu: Because `readlines` returns an Array and you're interested in the `encoding` method on the Strings inside the Array.

Comment: @muistooshort Yes! you are right,just i tried and found the need-fulness of that part.

Comment: You could also `.map(&:encoding)` if you prefer.

Comment: @muistooshort Like this one also :)